# Add a custom header in JSQMessageView Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, header, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

In my chat application I am using JSQMessagesViewController for rendering the conversation. For starting a conversation i've to add recipients in header of View controller & header should grow with number of recipients.

> **How can i achieve this ?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hide default navigation bar and prepare custom view by using DWlist to get header like that.

Custom view :

```
// Initalise and set the frame of the tag list
tagList = [[DWTagList alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 70.0f, 280.0f, 300.0f)];

// Add the items to the array
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Foo", @"Tag Label 1", @"Tag Label 2", @"Tag Label 3", @"Tag Label 4", @"Tag Label 5", nil];

[tagList setTags:array];

// Add the taglist to your UIView

[self.view addSubview:tagList];
```

https://github.com/domness/DWTagList